# how to stop our instance if idle for 30 min in aws cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have setup aws cloud watch

**Here is below detail set in our cloud watch**

- Metric name: CPUUtilization
- Statistic: average
- Period: 5 min
- Threshold Type: Static
- Whenever CPUUtilization is Lower/Equal then 10
- Datapoints to alarm: 1 out of 1
- Missing data treatment: Treat missing data as missing

**EC2 action:**

- Alarm state trigger: In Alarm
- Take the following action: stop this instance

**After 5 min our server still does not stop with the cloud watch in aws.**

[image]

Comment: 5 minute is long. CW alarms are not real-time. There is always some delay. Have you tried with detailed monitoring and 1 minute period? Delay should be smaller.

Answer (score 2):

At Feb 2022 you have these options:

1. You can use Alarms to automate shutdown and terminate instances:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/launch-resource-optimization-recommendations/

2. You can view idle instances in CUR recommendations : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/01/08/use-amazon-cloudwatch-to-detect-and-shut-down-unused-amazon-ec2-instances/

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SQS queue whose target is a Python Lambda function. The python lambda function can use boto to turn off the ec2 instance.

Then you can set this SQS as an alarm action for your Cloudwatch Alarm. You can find more details here:

https://medium.com/geekculture/automatically-turn-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-31fedd363cad

Terraform setup:

https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) to trigger a Lambda that will perform the stop instance call on the ec2 instance.